# Need help to transform the code for removing punctuation from Java string into recursion

Tags: java, string

I have come up with a solution for removing punctuation from a String in Java.Need to convert this into a recursive method.I would be thankful if someone can help me to solve this.

The code is as below:

```
public class punctuationRemove {

//private static String punc = "[][(){},.;!?<>%]";
 static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 static char[] punc = "',.;!?(){}[]<>%".toCharArray();

 public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "Hello!, how are you?";
        System.out.println(removePuntuation(s));
    }

 public static String removePuntuation(String s)
 {
     String tmp;
     boolean fl=true;

     for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++)
     {
         fl=true;
         char strChar=s.charAt(i);
         for (char badChar : punc) 
         {
            if (badChar == strChar)
            {
               fl=false;
               break;
             }
          }

          if(fl)
          {
             sb.append(strChar);
           }
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: "Need to convert this into a recursive method" - the only reason people `NEED` to convert to recursive (that I've seen) is because that is what their homework asks them to do...

Comment: @John3136:  Whether or not this is a homework exercise is neither here nor there.

Comment: @Makoto It is when the person asking has shown no effort at all and appears to be trying to hide the fact it is homework.

Comment: there is no need to use recursion.. A simple replaceAll() with appropriate REGEX will do it.. One line..

Comment: @John3136:  I doubt that they're hiding that fact, first.  Second, they may be stuck on the best algorithm or approach.  Just because it's a homework assignment doesn't mean that it immediately deserves to be closed.  Although, I suppose that's a tangent all unto itself right now.

Comment: I second @Makoto. The OP has shown his code and effort. He doesn't want to use a *simpler* approach. yes, this might be a homework question, still it is not of *bad quality*.

Comment: dear members, Thanks for helping me to understand.This is not for any homework. I am a developer.I was solving some of the problems of the textbook on the algorithm. I tried different methods. But it didn't work. I know its not a forum to help for homework.

Comment: But we all are here to share our knowledge and help each to build up their understanding of the concept. 
If someone is asking a question doesn't always mean that the person is lazy and need instant help. 
I am a learner and we all should encourage the concerns of the person asking a question instead of simply passing some guessed assumption.

Comment: So kindly try to think about the different possibilities when someone asks for a help.
There are many beginers like me who get stuck at times.They just need some insight to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion usually has two parts to it:

- A **base case** in which all recursion stops and a result is returned, and
- An **iterative step** in which recursion continues.

How does one recursively examine each character of a String?  They only look at the first character and send the substring from 1 to the end of it off to a recursive call.

As an example:

```
public String splitRecursive(String s) {
    if(!s.isEmpty()) {
        return s.charAt(0) + splitRecursive(s.substring(1));
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Let's think about that for a moment - so long as the string isn't empty (i.e. *base case*), then I should take the first character I get and append that to the result of another call (i.e. *iterative step*), which takes the substring from 1 to however many characters are left.  If it *is* empty, I just return the empty string.

This skeleton piece of code is actually 3/4ths of what you need to work out your problem.  You need to augment it to insepct the character to see if it is one of your punctuation characters you've already isolated.

Consider your iterative step:  if you see punctuation, what should you do?  If you don't see punctuation, what should you do?  I leave the rest as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you,

```
public class RemovePunctuations {

public static int i = 0;
public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "Hello!, how are you?";
        System.out.println(removePuntuation(s));
    }
```

Using Recursion,

```
public static String removePuntuation(String s){
    char [] charArray = s.toCharArray();
            if(!Character.isLetter(charArray[i]) && !Character.isSpaceChar(charArray[i])){
                s = s.replace(String.valueOf(charArray[i]), "");
                i--;
            }
            i++;
            if(i<s.length())
                return removePuntuation(s);
        return s;
}

}
```

You can get the same result from the following way without using recursion,

```
public static String removePuntuation(String s){
     char [] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            if(!Character.isLetter(charArray[i]) && !Character.isSpaceChar(charArray[i])){
                s = s.replace(String.valueOf(charArray[i]), "");
            }
        }
        return s;
}
```